# jQuery Ajax - Show line breaks in response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using this simple script to get the response using Ajax from a PHP file..

```
           $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'response.php',
                type: 'get',
                dataType:'text',
                success: function(data){
                    jQuery(".results").text(data);
                }
            }

<?php
   echo "1<br />";
   echo "2<br />";
   echo "3<br />";
   echo "4<br />";
   echo "5<br />";
   echo "6<br />";
   echo "7<br />";
   echo "8<br />";
?>
```

This works but does not show the line breaks, is there a way to get it so that jQuery shows it with the line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're dumping the response via `text()`, which treats what you pass to it as just that, i.e. text.

Use `html()` instead.

```
jQuery(".results").html(data);
```